# Why does my form not recognize an initiated instance of a class on another form?

Tags: vb.net

I have three components right now: Form1, Form2, and a Module where my class code is located.

Module:

```
Public Class myClass
   public x as integer
End Class
```

I initiated an instance in Form1:

```
...
dim newClass as myClass = New myClass
newClass.x = 1
...
```

Everything on Form1 works as it should. My problem is that when I try to access this instance, newClass, from Form2, it isn't recognized. Is there any way to fix this?

The test code I'm entering into Form2 is:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If newClass.x = 1 then
            msgbox("success")
        end if

    End Sub

End Class
```

Like I said, the problem is that while myClass is recognized by Form2 as a public class, it has no idea what newClass is.

Comment: What type of Basic? VB.Net? You should include a more specific tag (if available)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site. I tried to look for the tag but basic was all I could figure out how to select. It is vb.net

Comment: Welcome to SO. The tag was under `vb` rather than `basic`. I just added it.

Comment: `newClass` is an instance of your class in a variable.  This variable is scoped to `Form1` and will never be visible to `Form2`.  The variable either needs to be declared in a higher scope that is visible to both forms or depending on the order-of-operation presented by your use-case you might be able to pass the instance variable from 'Form1' to 'Form2' when the second form is instantianted.  See this article for an example of passing: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/tutors-corner/147563-passing-variables-controls-using-winforms-vb-net.html

Comment: How would I declare it in a higher scope? I tried declaring it in the module, but then I got the same error but now in both forms. 

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that shows what's going on with your code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a = New A()
    Dim b = New B()
End Sub

Public Class A

    Public x As X = New X()
End Class

Public Class B
    Public Sub Method()
        Console.WriteLine(x)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class X

End Class
```

Here, on the `Console.WriteLine(x)` line I get the error "BC30109 'X' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression". VB.Net is not case-sensitive so it thinks I'm referring to the class.

Now, the reason it didn't see your instance is because `x` is defined within `A` so it is out of scope for `B`.

To make it visible you can do this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a = New A()
    Dim b = New B()
    b.x = a.x
End Sub

Public Class A

    Public x As X = New X()
End Class

Public Class B

    Public x As X = Nothing

    Public Sub Method()
        Console.WriteLine(x)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class X

End Class
```

The other option is to pass `x` thru the constructor of `B`, but I didn't structure my example to show this nicely.

Comment: Yea, I think I'm going to have to research the pass-thru option because I need to manipulate the variables across forms. 

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @JoseLopez - Then you'll need to define a constructor in `Form2` that takes `newClass As myClass` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Form1 creates Form2, pass Form1 to Form2 via the Show() method:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public x As Integer
End Class

Public Class Form1

    Public SC As New SomeClass

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SC.x = 911
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f2 As New form2
        f2.show(Me) ' <-- pass Form1 to Form2 via "Me"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Over in Form2, you cast the .Owner() property to Type Form1 and store it locally for use:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private F1 As Form1

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.F1 = DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form1)
        Me.Text = F1.SC.x
    End Sub

End Class
```

Note how I'm using `F1.SC.x` to access the instance of SomeClass that is within our Form1 instance.